# How to bind AngularJS Calendar to a REST resource using MVP

Tags: model-view-controller, data-binding, angularjs, fullcalendar, angularjs-directive

I’m failing to implement the binding between my REST resource and the AngluarJS calendar control. It seems that I’m missing something or just don’t get it logically since all components are working as long as there are separate. I used this Plunker as example of a calendar implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/VbYDNK?p=preview

Inside the view:

```
...
<div ng-controller="CalendarCtrl" dev-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources" style="padding-top: 30px;"></div>
...
```

Inside the controller:

```
     xyz.controller('MainController', function($scope, $location, $rootScope, MainModel) {
        ...
        // REST call - getPendingObjectsByUser
            $scope.pendingobjects = MainModel.pendingObjectsByUser.get(
                    {userId : $rootScope.currentUser.userId}, 
                        function(response) {                    

                            // do something                                         

                    }, function(response) {

                        if(response.status == 404) {
                            $location.path('/notFound');
                        } else if (response.status == 500) {
                            $location.path('/error');
                        }       


                    });
    // this works fine              
    ...
    function CalendarCtrl($scope) {

            var date = new Date();var d = date.getDate();var m = date.getMonth();var y = date.getFullYear();

                $scope.events = [{type:'birthday', title: 'Brian',start: new Date(y, m, 1)}];

                $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

                $scope.uiConfig = {
                  calendar:{
                    height: 450, editable: false, defaultView: 'month'
                  }
                };
        }
// this also works fine
```

Now I'm trying to do a simple binding like:

```
 $scope.events = [{title: $scope.pendingobjects.objectsData[0].title , type:'birthday', start: new Date(y, m, 1)}]
```

but due to the asynchronous behavior its “undefined”. If I put the whole $scope.events into the response function where it is available (like shown below), the calendar doesn’t work anymore.

```
 // getPendingObjectsByUser
            $scope.pendingobjects = MainModel.pendingObjectsByUser.get(
                    {userId : $rootScope.currentUser.userId}, 
                        function(response) {                    

                            // do something
                            $scope.events = [{type:'birthday', title:'$scope.pendingobjects.objectsData[0].title',start: new Date(y, m, 1)}]                                                                                        

 }, function(response) {

                        if(response.status == 404) {
                            $location.path('/notFound');
                        } else if (response.status == 500) {
                            $location.path('/error');
                        }       

                    })
```

Do I need to work with promises or am I just to confused to see my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Why not bind the events to the Resource straight away? 
like so:

```
$scope.events = function (start, end, callback) {
  var events = MainModel.pendingObjectsByUser.get({
    userId : $rootScope.currentUser.userId
  });

  // Promise 
  events.$promise.then(function (val) {
          $scope.events = events;
          callback($scope.events);
      }
  );
};
      $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
```